# Agile - Learning & Practicing Agile alone

Tags: agile

I am learning new technologies and doing some small projects to practice these technologies alone. And I want to learn the agile methodolgy along the way but don't know if it's a good or bad idea to learn it alone and how far I can go with it.

Another thing what good resources to learn it (books/articles)?

Comment: Related (although IMHO not exact duplicate) threads: [Agile for the Solo Developer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/220/agile-for-the-solo-developer); [Using Agile development in a one person team](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/50658/using-agile-development-in-a-one-person-team)

Comment: See also [What good book shoud I buy to learn Agile from scratch?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-good-book-shoud-i-buy-to-learn-agile-from-scratch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Practices of an Agile Developer]

Have a look at the book called **[Practices of an Agile Developer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/097451408X)**. It covers aspects such as the development process, attitudes as an agile developer, management-related topics, and of course, what to do when coding. It's a nice one.

Answer (score 1):

Agile Adoption Patterns: A Roadmap to Organizational Success by Amr Elssamadisy

Agile and Iterative Development: A Manager’s Guide by Craig Larman

Agile Estimating and Planning by Mike Cohn

Agile Project Management: Creating Innovative Products by Jim Highsmith

Agile Retrospectives: Making Good Teams Great by Esther Derby and Diana Larsen

Agile Software Development by Alistair Cockburn

Agile Software Development with Scrum by Ken Schwaber and Mike Beedle

Becoming Agile: ...in an imperfect world by Greg Smith and Dr. Ahmed Sidky

The Business Value of Agile Software Methods: Maximizing Roi with Just-In-Time Processes and 
Documentation by David F. Rico, Hasan H. Sayani, and Saya Sone

Collaboration Explained by Jean Tabaka

Crystal Clear: A Human-Powered Methodology for Small Teams by Alistair Cockburn

Encyclopedia of Software Engineering edited by Phillip A. Laplante

Extreme Programming Explained: Embrace Change by Kent Beck

Fearless Change by Linda Rising and Mary Lynn Manns

Innovation Games: Creating Breakthrough Products Through Collaborative Play by Luke Hohmann

Lean Software Development – An Agile Toolkit for Software Development Managers by Mary and 
Tom Poppendieck

Lean Solutions by Jim Womack and Dan Jones

Lean Thinking by Jim Womack and Dan Jones

Managing Agile Projects by Sanjiv Augustine

Managing the Design Factory by Donald G. Reinertsen

Planning Extreme Programming by Kent Beck and Martin Fowler

Scaling Lean & Agile Development: Thinking and Organizational Tools for Large-Scale Scrum by 
Craig Larman and Bas Vodde

The Software Project Manager's Bridge to Agility by Michele Sliger and Stacia Broderick

User Stories Applied by Mike Cohn

You can also go to http://agilescout.com as a great resource! :)

Answer (score 0):

Pick a project and try and do it as fast as possible. When your finished, review what you did. Work out how you can improve the project. Pick another project and incorporate those improvements into it. Repeat.

Comment: -1 that's not necessarily agile

Comment: @Steven A. Lowe - It may not be but it teaches you to constantly refine your development process and that is part of agile

Comment: hmmmm. ok so i get an idea, and i bang out some code, and after hacking at it for 72 hours straight it works. so i review the code and decide that things would go faster if i made less comments and used shorter variable names next time... _not agile_ ;-)